# Can't execute a bash script with python 2.2

Tags: python, bash, cgi

SO I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I have a cgi python script that needs to execute a bash script. I have the following line in my code:

```
os.system("/complete/path/to/executable/run_summary_page.sh " + labelName)
```

I've been trying to debug this for hours now and I can't find out why it doesn't execute that correctly. When I run the same exactly line from the command line it works perfectly fine. I have given correct permissions to that bash script and so on, but it still isn't working. Note, I'm forced to use python 2.2 so I'm a little restricted with the number of utilities I have available.

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: No, it seems like it runs the script fine. The code is embedded in between some html, and the html prints out without a hitch...

Comment: What does `os.system` return?

Comment: Can you check the return code?  `stat = os.system(...)`

Comment: Python 2.2 was released in 2001.  You should convince your organization to let you use software that's not 11 years out of date.

Comment: Wow, ya, the return code is 256. I want to know why it's failing, how do I get the stdout? And ya, you don't have to tell me twice about the outdated python lol. But I'm just an intern.

Comment: @de1337ed: see my answer for stdout

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember all of what is and isn't there back in python 2.2, but you can try a simple alternative for calling that command and seeing what is happening:

```
import commands
stat, output = commands.getstatusoutput("command")
```

That isn't the most robust way to run commands, but its an easy way to check whats going on right now. If the `stat` is `!= 0` then it failed. You should also be able to see both stdout and stderr in the `output`

If the `stat == 0` and there is nothing interesting in the `output`, then I suspect your bash script is encountering some circumstance, ending, and not really printing anything useful. Maybe it is expecting certain environment variables, and just ignoring and moving along happily when something isn't right.

Comment: Wow, this is actually helping me a lot. So because of the fact that we are using a shared file system, the command 'mv' isn't located at /bin/mv in the server that the site is running on. What's even more annoying is that they don't give me access to code on that server, they only give me access to code on a server that has access to the shared file system. I'm going to try and poke around some more and get back to you